# 2022: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2022 (and where did January go, right?) and dive head first into 2023, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Ukrainian Language over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 3 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 74 | 16 |
| Answers flagged | 0 | 89 |
| Comment flags handled | 19 | 1 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 52 | 65 |
| Comments flagged | 0 | 20 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 15 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 31 | 32 |
| Posts locked | 0 | 2 |
| Posts undeleted | 0 | 3 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 1 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 7 | 2 |
| Questions closed | 4 | 2 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 0 | 10 |
| Questions migrated | 2 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 0 | 9 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 0 | 1 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 0 | 14 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue | 0 | 50 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue | 0 | 43 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue | 0 | 44 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 7 | 72 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 2 | 17 |
| Users deleted | 1 | 0 |
| Users destroyed³ | 1 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 0 | 10 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Ukrainian Language](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). Community can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2021: a year in moderation](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/2021-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2023! ^_^

Comment: Tasks reviewed by Moderators: 7 during the entire year. This site badly deserves a better set of Moderators.

Comment: Actually, in an ideal site, _the community_ does most of the reviewing, not the moderators. Moderators having to step in to do those sorts of tasks usually signals a disengaged community. So the stats reported here in respect to review queues suggest a healthy community to me, and no case for concern with the moderation team.

Comment: sorry to say, but this is not the case. It is not "the community", quite often it is **only a single user** (me). You have admin permissions, check my 2022 stats for yourself: First Questions 40/43, First answers 44/50, and so on. Check my flags history: quite often, it takes **four full days** to process flags on clearly spam posts ([one](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6948/8), [two](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/7100/8)) (read: none of the Mods even bother to visit the site for 4 days).

Comment: When I used to be a Mod, I was disturbed by the fact I'm doing most moderatorship on my own. So I stepped down to open up the way to the community. Despite the fact I drastically reduced my activity here, and still it appears that I'm doing most of the job alone. And this has to be changed, I think. The existing Moderators had 5 years to prove their right for the diamond badge, and they failed miserably.

Comment: You're conflating two things, though: one of them (your original concern) was the fact that the moderation team only reviewed 7 posts from the "Low quality posts" review queue, and in response to that, I can only repeat what I said earlier — _the community_ should be in the review queues, in a community effort. Now, if the community here is not engaged enough in those efforts, which your comment seems to suggest, that's a separate matter; but the stats seem to suggest that is not the case, since the community _did_ handle the tasks, in bigger numbers than the mods.

Comment: Your second, _separate_, concern, relates to the moderators' response time with regards to flags. Looking at the moderation dashboard stats, I don't see anything worrisome — though four full days to address a spam flag are _definitely_ not ideal, once again I want to remind you that the community has the tools to address instances like the posts you linked to: if enough folks work to flag those posts as spam, the posts won't need moderator intervention to be deleted.

Comment: Re: 7 posts, I stand corrected, it is 9, not 7. Three per Mod per year. A totally different thing. :) Re: "since the community *did* handle the tasks", thanks, this addresses my concern. Let me refrain from Review queues throughout 2023 and, if we all stay alive and happy, let us get back to this discussion in 2024. Maybe this way my point would be more compelling. :) Re: "I don't see anything worrisome", thanks, this answers my concern.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine As I understand, you recommend to change moderators — in which I totally agree — but weʼd still have a problem — change with whom? In any case our siteʼd still be mostly backed by community or, yeah, mostly by you.